# Can $x^2+y^2,y^2+z^2,z^2+x^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2$ all be square numbers?

Tags: number-theory

I know that if we want $x^2+y^2$ to be square number, we are looking for pythagorean triple; if we want $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to be a square number, we are looking for pythagorean quadruple. But have we ever found any positive integers $x,y,z$ such that $x^2+y^2,y^2+z^2,z^2+x^2,x^2+y^2+z^2$ are all square numbers?

Comment: Might be nice to see an example of a Pythagorean quadruplet, as this is not something commonly known (in opposed to Pythagorean triplet).

Comment: @barakmanos $3^2+4^2+12^2=13^2$

Comment: What is the source of this problem?(if there is any)

Comment: For numbers you can write. http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1172008_combinations_of_numbers_in_squares

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: $1^2+2^2+2^2=3^2$.

Comment: @Roby5  ugly equation???  For me, they are beautiful!

Comment: @individ Sorry, if I offended you. I just wanted to know how you parametrised $a,b,c$ in terms of $t,k,N$?

Comment: No perfect cuboid please see below; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2662452/can-anyone-verify-or-discredit-my-proof-of-no-solution-to-the-perfect-cuboid-pro

Comment: @MohlomiCliffMakhetha Why are you answering a post from 2016 anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a famous open problem : [the perfect cuboid problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick#Perfect_cuboid)

Comment: That's another question.

Comment: I don't follow: a perfect cuboid is a cuboid whose edges $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers and such that the edge diagonals and the main diagonal are all integers, which is equivalent to $x^2 + y^2$, $x^2 + z^2$ and $y^2 + z^2$ on the one hand, and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ all being perfect squares. Isn't that exactly the OP's question?

Comment: @PseudoNeo Oops. Sorry my mistake. I thought space diagonals didn't include edge diagonals.